# JavaScript Throttle always returning function

Tags: javascript, throttling

I'm trying to understand JavaScript Throttling. I implemented a very basic throttle for the knowledge that I have so far.

```
const display = (msg) => {
    return msg;
}

const throttleDisplay = (func, limit) => {
    let flag = true;
    return function() {
        if(flag) {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            flag = false;
            setTimeout(() => flag = true, limit);
        }
    }
}

for(let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const result = throttleDisplay(display("Hi"), 6000); 
        console.log(result)
    }, i*1000);
}
```

My console.log is returning `[Function]` instead of the message `Hi`. Also, it is returning `[Function]` 5 times. Shouldn't it ignore the next call until the limit, 6000ms, has passed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Throttle is *supposed* to return a function, one that throttles calls to the passed in function so you can e.g. pass it to an event listener. You probably want something like (outside the loop) `const f = throttle(console.log, 6000);` then inside the loop `setTimeout(f, i*1000, 'hi')` Throttling isn't going to do anything if you pass a different throttled function to setTimeout every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throttling works differently.

First, you should name your throttle function just `throttle`, as it is not specifically linked with `display`. Then, you should call this `throttle` to get a function that *is* specific to `display`. And only then you would use that secondary function in the actual use case you have for it, i.e. with the timer.

Here is your code corrected:

```js
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
    let flag = true;
    return function() {
        if(flag) {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            flag = false;
            setTimeout(() => flag = true, limit);
        }
    }
};

const throttleDisplay = throttle(() => console.log("Hi"), 6000);

for(let i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    setTimeout(throttleDisplay, i*1000);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to have a display function passing the message that I want to console.log? Also, could you please give more details about ```func.apply(this, arguments)``` I'm not sure what it does. Sorry, throttling concept is new to me.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what the purpose is of your `display` function. It doesn't display anything, but returns the same thing you pass it. I don't see what the purpose is of such a function. That's why I just throttled `() => console.log("Hi")`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the function has no purpose. I'm using it to try to understand how I would be able to inside the ```throttle(() => // call a function, 6000)``` call a function and later log the response/return of this function

Comment: OK, but that was not your question. Your question was about the throttle always returning a function. It seems you are now moving the goal posts... If this is your new question, then please post it as a new question.